# How do we manage multiple html pages about css?

Tags: html, css, sass, package.json

I'm totally beginner, and I was wondering about page management in my folder. I'm creating a website that has 5 different pages, that are all located in the same folder. By the way I'm using sass for my css.

At the moment, I only have 1 css file, that was designed originaly for my first page. But now that I'm doing the 4 others, I'm wondering if :

- is it ok to create as many css file as I have html pages ? In my case I'd have 5 html page and 5 css.
- I don't know how to manage my sass : should I create 5 different package.json files ? Or I can create 5 different scss files, that would be compiled in 5 different css files ?  In this case should I create 5 different scripts in my package.json file that would indicate for each scss file the right css file ?

Sorry if my questions are not clear , as well as my english. Thank you so much guys.

Comment: If those files are all the same, use the same for each pages. If there' a few difference as addition , add them to that single css page, else if this is the same rules with different values, then you may add a second file to a page that requires modification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am no expert in sass but I can give you the CSS file management for your HTML file. By the way everyone will have their own suggestion. Create a common CSS file. In this file you will add your default theme for all pages. Then connect it with all the HTML files, And finally for individual CSS for each page, do it in the style tags in your HTML pages.

Comment: @Neo78 this does not answer the question you asked

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a lot about sass either, but for CSS, I would recommend creating one CSS file for all of your HTML files. Then, you can create a base style for all of your pages (styling that's the same for all pages). For individual CSS (CSS that changes per page),  you could:

- Use classes
- Put your individual styling in the style tag in the head of your html page

I think using classes is easier, especially if you have a common style for all of your pages, but it's up to you. Hopefully that helped!

Comment: Thank you so much guys, it really helped me out. I just have this question left about SASS and package.json but I'll find out soon I hope ! Thank you guys ! :)